# How can i create a String object from literal in Java ? e.g. string with special characters

Tags: java, string

how can i create a String object from literal ? e.g. i have

```
String s = " `<div id="top_bin">` ";
```

this gives an error `syntax error on token`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes used inside the `String`. Use `\"` for that:

```
String s = " <div id=\"top_bin\"> ";
                     ^        ^
```

Comment: thanks - it does solve part of a problem.